# Disable hardware brightness adjustment

Tags: windows-10, laptop

I have a laptop, I bought it second hand about a year ago and its always had this problem:

The f12 key doesn't work and the print screen button to the right of it is also temperamental. The fact the key doesn't work isn't the main issue, the main issue is ALL the time **the laptop will randomly increase the brightness leaving the windows brightness slider overlaying the screen until the decrease brightness button is pressed.**

This must be a low-level hardware problem because I have used a key disable tool to disable the f12 (brightness) key and the problem still persists. I think the best solution if it is possible, would be to disable the changing of brightness through hardware and only allow brightness to be modified using the slider in the settings of windows.

Additionally, whilst we are here, is there a way to get rid of windows 10 overlays entirely? I really don't like them.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: On some laptops, in BIOS you can set that the Fn key be pressed to enable normal F1 through F12 keys... If you don't mind needing to use the Fn key on occasion, then make that change.